# Where clause and inner join syntax query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select SUM(pass_count) ,SUM(fail_count),SUM(blocked_count),SUM(no_run_count)
from TAble1(nolock) table1
where owasp_id = (1,2,3,4,5,8)
inner join 
Table 2 table2
on
TAble1.build_detail_id = table2.build_detail_id 
where 
 TAble1.build_detail_id in(
select top 6 bdt.build_detail_id from table3 bdt order by 1 desc)
and table1.test_run_id=1
```

I am getting syntax error and I would like to get the sum of passcount ,fail count  where owasp_id= 1,2,3,4,5,8 and do inner join with table 2 for build detail id. Can any one help in this?

Comment: The database comes with an excellent documentation that describes the correct syntax and usage of keywords. Why not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three syntax errors, the first two breaks the query, the third is a strong recommendation:

1. `WHERE` should come after `FROM` and any `JOIN` clauses.
2. `owasp_id = (1,2,3,4,5,8)` should be `owasp_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,8)` as you're supplying multiple values.
3. Leaving out `WITH`for table hints (`NOLOCK`) is deprecated and should be avoided.

So the query should probably look like this:

```
select SUM(pass_count) ,SUM(fail_count),SUM(blocked_count),SUM(no_run_count)
from Table1 WITH (nolock) table1
inner join Table2 table2 on TAble1.build_detail_id = table2.build_detail_id 
where owasp_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,8)
AND Table1.build_detail_id in(
    select top 6 bdt.build_detail_id from table3 bdt order by 1 desc)
and table1.test_run_id=1
```

Whether the query will work as intended I can't say, but it should be correct syntactically at least.